# CodeIgniter Session Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, session

I am using CodeIgniter for a college project and need to store sessions.

In my first controller, login, I get the users ID and store it in session then I redirect to a dashboard but the session data is lost. I am storing the session data in a database and it displays a new record when I get to dashboard page but the id is not set. It does get set after initial login but redirect loses it.

Here is the login controller: http://viper-7.com/PEIcLC

Here is my dashboard controller: http://viper-7.com/mIUPJb

Here is my config settings:

```
 $config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
 $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
 $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
 $config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
 $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
 $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Are you loading the session library in autoload.php? $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'template'); Also, since you removed the second 'sess_cookie_name' try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: @nullReference im not loading template?

Comment: You don't need it. I just pasted what was in one of my configs.

Comment: @nullReference ok. I am autoloading session anyway

Comment: You make reference to a loginUser model. Could you please show that?